# Write React/Framework components and build pure html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frameworks

What i'm trying to accomplish is to build tool that will let me build website like lego blocks. This way i will have most unique blogs without too much coding. For example i want 100 wordpress looking blogs. Each blog will have header/main/sidebar/footer. So i'm thinking about coding 5 headers, 5 main, 5 sidebar, 5 footer each as component. Then i will randomly use header A, main B, sidebar C, footer D and voila i have first blog :) The blogs needs to be as unique as they can be using this method. Second important this is that i have to have them as html/css not js. So i was looking for framework that will let me achive this. First i was looking at gatsbyjs, but i cannot get html files, then i tried nextjs because there at build U can export html. But in simple blog with only one main page i got such index.html

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="2" />
    <noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/main-925041ce925730787a8a.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-50bee04d1dc61f8adf5b.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/framework.6323d7e8995473683279.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/f6078781a05fe1bcb0902d23dbbb2662c8d200b3.964928bcb82fd5c6065f.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-0a8231baaa9660ceaca9.js"
      as="script"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-7638f3314f35e6ffac1c.js"
      as="script"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="__next"><div>Welcome to the Next.js blog</div></div>
    <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
      {
        "props": { "pageProps": {} },
        "page": "/",
        "query": {},
        "buildId": "ElUp7syt_UnrlISSJbfd4",
        "nextExport": true,
        "autoExport": true,
        "isFallback": false
      }
    </script>
    <script
      nomodule=""
      src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-4acaa4b69e5977b3ab87.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/main-925041ce925730787a8a.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-50bee04d1dc61f8adf5b.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/framework.6323d7e8995473683279.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/f6078781a05fe1bcb0902d23dbbb2662c8d200b3.964928bcb82fd5c6065f.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-0a8231baaa9660ceaca9.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-7638f3314f35e6ffac1c.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/ElUp7syt_UnrlISSJbfd4/_buildManifest.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
    <script
      src="/_next/static/ElUp7syt_UnrlISSJbfd4/_ssgManifest.js"
      async=""
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>```

Its a lot of scripts that i don't really need. Then i was thinking maybe jekyll but also couldnt find html to export. So now i.m writing here, because maybe some of U know any framework that will let me accomplish what i'm trying to do?
````

Comment: Please provide a clear question. Your post should contain at least one question mark.

Answer (score -1):

see if you want your app to be dynamic then you need to use js or its library or frameworks. Since you have a pre written code in html/css so you can use React https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html which can be easily added to your html/css code.

Comment: I dont need dynamic in it :) I need some framework to get html/css out of it. I will then store it in database and choose randomly :)

Comment: so how would you choose randomly you need some programming language. that you can easily do by using react